# Cannot install any plugin from Jenkins server on setup. Error: Read timeout

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins on docker on my local machine with the official `jenkins/jenkins:lts` image. Until a few days ago, it still worked like a charm, but now it is unable to install any suggested package.
I checked the logs and found something about unreachable plugin mirror servers.

None of any plugin installed.

```
Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/.../1.7/plain-credentials.hpi to /var/jenkins_home/plugins/plain-credentials.jpi.tmp
```

I have tried on a couple of machines on different networks and got the same errors, I wonder if it was something relating to server maintenance? I'm from South East Asia. Do you have any idea? Do you have any workaround? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been getting similar errors since 2020-11-12. It seems that Jenkins infrastructure is having trouble right now, which is being tracked in the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/issues/3958

Comment: That is exact what I encountered at this moment. Does this happen frequently? Because I think it's crucial to maintain the availability of such service.

Comment: I have been using Jenkins for six or seven years and this is the first time I've seen errors like this or been unable to update plugins automatically for more than a day. None of the updates are important to me, so I'm just waiting until things are fixed. The above issue has discussions of how to install plugins manually. Several years ago, I had a different problem updating plugins intermittently, though that was probably specific to the local network I was using at the time.